# Where to find IP address in file system (e.g. proc or sys)

Tags: networking, file-system, ip-address

Is there a way to get the IP (v4) address of an interface in the file system of Android? I know I could use ifconfig or netcfg but I would like to use a monitoring tool which can only access files and not execute commands.

Answer (score 3):

I have no *Android* to test it, but Linux offers:

```
 cat /proc/net/fib_trie
```

.. from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365225/how-to-get-the-ipv4-address-for-an-interface-from-proc

The output can then be filtered further by grep, e.g.

```
 cat /proc/net/fib_trie|grep '|--' | grep -vE ' 127|\.0[^0-9.]*$|\.255[^0-9.]*$'
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [a post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10514995/2533433), `cat /proc/net/tcp` will return it in

> the second column, with the heading "local_address", e.g. "CF00A8C0:0203".
>
> The part after ":" is a port number.
>
> From the rest use the last two (C0) as a hex number, e.g. C0 is 192, which is the start of the address in this example.

Further:

> The IP address is displayed as a little-endian four-byte hexadecimal number; that is, the least significant byte is listed first, so you'll need to reverse the order of the bytes to convert it to an IP address.
>
> The port number is a simple two-byte hexadecimal number.

Comment: unfortunately that does not work on my phone. that file only has the headers but no data. i'm using android 4.4.2 on a SGS4.

Comment: ah i see. there is only data if tcp connections are active. that's not so practical for my purpose.

Comment: You could also check with `/proc/net/arp`, but I'm not sure if that has the very same restriction. What should work, however, is looking at the device information in `/proc/net/dev`, and picking the desired interface (e.g. `tiwlan0` for WiFi in most cases).

Comment: /proc/net/arp is empty as well on my phone and /proc/net/dev does only contain statistics but not the IP address. :-(

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Until someone else can give a definite answer, you might do a `ls` on `/proc/net` (and `/sys/...`) to check for promising candidates.

Comment: Have you checked /proc/sys/net? Also try running ipaddr from terminal emulator.

Comment: I've just checked on an off-line device. Looks like `/proc/net/tcp` holds something (remote_addr being 0.0.0.0, so "idle"), again using hex values (as described in my answer). In my case `0100007F` as `local_address`, which matches `127.0.0.1` aka localhost. Looks like that's what you're after?